# Typescript: Return the `instance type` of the `typeof class`

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0, typescript-generics

I have a function that when you input the `Class name` or the `Class constructor`, it will return the instance of that Class:

```ts
type ConstructorOf<C> = { new (...args: any[]): C; };

const ClassMap = {
  'Class1': Class1,
  'Class2': Class2,
};

function getInstance<Cls>(c: ConstructorOf<Cls>): Cls;
function getInstance<N extends keyof typeof ClassMap>(key: N): typeof ClassMap[N]; // It return typeof Class1/Class2
function getInstance<N extends keyof typeof ClassMap, Cls>(key: N | ConstructorOf<Cls>) {
  if (typeof m === 'string') {
    return CreateInstance(ClassMap[key]);
  }
  return CreateInstance(key);
}
```

The 2nd definition of `getInstance` is not what I wanted, because it returns the `typeof Class` but not the `Class`

How should I modify this part?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can just use the `InstanceType` built-in conditional type:

```
function getInstance<Cls>(c: ConstructorOf<Cls>): Cls;
function getInstance<N extends keyof typeof ClassMap>(key: N): InstanceType<typeof ClassMap[N]>; 
function getInstance<N extends keyof typeof ClassMap, Cls>(key: N | ConstructorOf<Cls>) {
  return null!
}

let o = getInstance("Class1"); // Class1
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=17&ssc=41&pln=11&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwM7AE4FcDGw6oPIBmAPDAHxQC8UA3lAhAO5QAUAdOwIaoDmSAXFA4IQAbQC6ASgEwA3FAC+MgFBLMAGw5IksDVoCMNBat3aYJgEyH5KzIhQ7NSALIcwlGkqhQA5Gcd7vaRM9ABpPHz8tc0CHKLDFFQJ0BGwAS0QobghgAElkYCFMCBI1JFJmTGk7NCwcfGIzMqkdJGUklOB0hEzsvJRC4oA5KAgAD2AIBAATbQBrCBA4AihQSCXY51dy+ZABQea+gpSIABVwYtWIdcjNsBFBsVI5JXa0jKzc-IGiYbGJ6bmC3Wl2uJhcYBCLW2Cz2UAAPrBqhhsLhCCUmh4vKhsuhUN0EOg1GoAIRKaxKNTZKBwdwfQ4DZgAIhuekZEjkAHoORs9EA)